# Was a test (NUnit3) invoked from Visual Studio or from a command line runner?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit-3.0

Is there a way to tell if a test (NUnit3) has been invoked from Visual Studio rather than executed from a command line runner? I need to provide the equivalent of the command line parameters (--p) when developing the tests in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer to the question you asked, but an answer to your problem...

> I need to provide the equivalent of the command line parameters (--p) when developing the tests in Visual Studio.

Are you aware you can pass the equivalent of `--p` into the adapter using a .runsettings file? The fragment you'd need looks like this:

```
<TestRunParameters>
  <Parameter name="webAppUrl" value="http://localhost" />
  <Parameter name="webAppUserName" value="Admin" />
  <Parameter name="webAppPassword" value="Password" />
</TestRunParameters>
```

Here's the NUnit documentation for `.runsettings`. Note it's a little outdated, and doesn't mention the `TestRunParameters` setting.

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Tips-And-Tricks

Here's a guide as to where to stick the file in the first place:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx